# Function with zero Wirtinger derivative (with respect to conjugate)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $f(z)=(a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2)+(b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2)\bar{z}+(c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2)\bar{z}^2$ where the $a,b,c$'s are all constant, such that its (Wirtinger) derivative w.r.t. $\bar{z}$ is zero everywhere on the plane, I want to show that all $b_i$'s and $c_i$'s must be zero, or give a counterexample otherwise.

Here's my attempt. Since the derivative can be easily determine (e.g., this derivative for $C\bar{z}^k$ is just $kC\bar{z}^{k-1}$, and $z$ is considered constant w.r.t. $\bar{z}$), I get $b_0=0$ as desired by putting $z=0$, but I'm not sure if this is the correct method to get all the values of $b$'s and $c$'s.

Or, does the hypothesis mean that $f(z)$ is entire?

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Under this condition the $\overline z$ derivative of the third term is holomorphic.

Comment: @WimC I see. It's because it is a polynomial, right? What does it imply? Perhaps I just get lost in the so-many concepts related to holomorphicity.

Comment: @WimC Is it like this: Since the $\bar{z}$ derivative of the third term is holomorphic, one more $\bar{z}$ derivative of it should be zero everywhere, implying the polynomial $c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2$ is zero everywhere, hence the $c$'s are zero. Using similar argument after removing the third term, the $b$'s are zero too. How is this?

Comment: That’s exactly right. You can write that as an answer to you own question.

Comment: @WimC I see. I just did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question based on the hint by @WimC's comment:

By writing the $\bar{z}$-derivative of $f$ being zero everywhere, it is readily seen that $2(c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2)\bar{z}$ is a polynomial, hence entire. This means that its $\bar{z}$-derivative is also zero everywhere, so that $c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2=0$ everywhere, forcing all $c_0,c_1,c_2$ to be zero as desired. Hence, $f(z)$ now only involves the first and second terms. Again by writing the $\bar{z}$-derivative of this $f$ which is zero everywhere, this gives $b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2=0$ everywhere. Thus, $b_0,b_1,b_2$ are zero as desired.